# Retornar valor do select asp.net core MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp, entity-framework-core

Bom Dia,

Estou com uma duvida, eu tenho uma aplicação em asp.net core.
Ao selecionar um DropDownList quero receber esse valor sem precisar apertar no botão de submit, porém não sei como fazer, alguém poderia me dar uma Luz?

```
        <text>Nome Cliente: </text> @Html.DropDownList("IdCliente", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaClientes, "IdCliente", "NomeCliente"), "--SELECT--", new { @id = "myForm", @class = "myclass" })
```

Meu ViewBag no controller.

```
            //VIEW BAG PRA MOSTRAR OS CLIENTES
        ViewBag.ListaClientes = _context.Cliente.Select(
            a => new { a.IdCliente, a.NomeCliente }).ToList();
```

preciso receber esse IdCliente para fazer outro select para mostrar os Projetos, porém não consigo retornar o Id sem enviar a requisição, queria algo em tempo real.
Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: faça uma chamada `ajax`, que pode ser disparada no evento `change` do dropdown

Comment: Para acrescentar ao que disse o @RicardoPontual vê minha resposta [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204086/3990896).